# PowerPoint crashes while running excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have currently written an Excel VBA code which creates 40+ PowerPoint Slides.
However, while running this code PowerPoint crashes after creating 22 slides.
This issue only occurs when the VBA code is run **at one go**. Because, when I try to run the same code **line by line** it runs successfully till end.

For me this is something weird. Do we have any suggestion for this problem ?

**=> My code till creation of slide 2 is listed below (thereafter it create the other slides one after another till 43rd Slide)**

Regards,
Alok

```
Sub test25()

Dim pApp  As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pSlid As PowerPoint.Slide

Set pApp = New PowerPoint.Application

pApp.Visible = True
pApp.Activate

Set pPres = pApp.Presentations.Open("C:\.....\Template.pptx")

pPres.Slides(1).Select
Sheets("S01").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:P27").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.copy
pPres.Slides(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText

pPres.Slides(2).Duplicate
pPres.Slides(2).Select
Sheets("S02").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:P27").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.copy
pPres.Slides(2).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: Hi, Code added for your reference. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple potential issues, some of which are just code improvements.

On the line:

```
pPres.Slides(2).Duplicate
```

You are referring to slide 2, but you have not yet created slide 2 (as this is the line that creates it).  Change this to:

```
pPres.Slides(1).Duplicate
```

I don't see how your code is running, even line by line, without that...unless 'template.pptx' already has all of the slides (in which case, why are you duplicating?  I assumed 'template.pptx only contained the first slide)

Initially I suspected a [race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition), but typically VBA handles these well.  To be sure, and just general good practice, you may want to use a variable to refer to the current slide, instead of just a number (you already have the variable declared)

```
Set pSlid = pPres.Slides(1)
Sheets("S01").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:P27").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.copy
pSlid.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText

Set pSlid = pSlid.Duplicate
...
```

Also for your own convenience, you way want to look into using a [loop](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/study/vba-for-loop/), like:

```
Set pSlid = pPres.Slides(1)
For i = 1 to 43
  Sheets("S" & Format(CStr(i), "00")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:P27").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.copy
  pSlid.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText

  Set pSlid = pSlid.Duplicate
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments they are very useful. However, I have template.xlsx which already contains more than 1 slides and they need to be referred as per the data which is required to paste on that certain slide. That is the reason sometimes I directly select the slide or sometimes I duplicate that. I am going to your use your suggestion. I will keep you posted about the same